# Returning extra data as part of return type

Tags: scala, k-means

Below is an implementation of kmeans algorithm :

```
package com

object Functions {

  def distance(l1: (Array[Double], Array[Double])) = {

    val t = l1._1.zip(l1._2) 
    t.map(m => Math.abs(m._1 - m._2)).sum

  } 

}

package com

import com.Functions._

case class Point(label : String, points : Array[Double]) 

object KMeans2 extends Application {

  val points = List(("A1,2,10"), ("A2,2,5"), ("A3,8,4"), ("A4,5,8"), ("A5,7,5"), ("A6,6,4"), ("A7,1,2"), ("A8,4,9"))

  var initialCenters = Iterable[Array[Double]](Array(2, 10), Array(5, 8), Array(1, 2))

  val toDouble = points.map(m => new Point(m.split(",").head , m.split(",").tail.map(m2 => m2.toDouble)))

  val k = 3
  val maxNumberOfIterations = 10
  for (i <- 1 to maxNumberOfIterations) {

    val newCentres = getNewCenters(initialCenters)
    initialCenters = newCentres._2
    val map = newCentres._1

    for (a <- initialCenters.toList) {
      println(a.toList)
      for(m <- map){
        println("m is "+m._1.mkString(",")+","+m._2.flatten)
      }
    }

    println("");
  }

  def getNewCenters(initialCenters: Iterable[Array[Double]]): (Map[Array[Double],List[Array[Double]]] , Iterable[Array[Double]]) = {

    val joined = toDouble.map(m => initialCenters.map(p => (m.points, p))).flatten

    val grouped = joined.map(m => (m, distance((m)))).grouped(3).toList
    val sorted = grouped.map(m => m.sortBy(_._2).take(1)).flatten.map(m => m._1)
    val mapped = sorted.groupBy(_._2).map { case (k, v) => (k, v.map(_._1)) }

    val averaged = mapped.values.map(m => m.transpose.map(xs => xs.sum / xs.size).toArray)

    (mapped , averaged)

  }

}
```

I'm attempting to modify the getNewCenters function so that the point labels for each cluster are returned. The labels range from A1....A9

The closest I've got is returning the points themselves associated with each cluster. This is `mapped` element of returned `Tuple` `(mapped , average)`

How can the labels also be returned ?

So output should be (does not have to be exact data structure)

```
List(1.5, 3.5)
m is 1.0,2.0,List(2.0, 5.0, A2, 1.0, 2.0, A7)
m is 2.0,10.0,List(2.0, 10.0 , A1)
m is 5.0,8.0,List(8.0, 4.0, A3, 5.0, 8.0, A4, 7.0, 5.0, A5, 6.0, 4.0, A6, 4.0, 9.0, A8)
```

instead of :

```
List(1.5, 3.5)
m is 1.0,2.0,List(2.0, 5.0, 1.0, 2.0)
m is 2.0,10.0,List(2.0, 10.0)
m is 5.0,8.0,List(8.0, 4.0, 5.0, 8.0, 7.0, 5.0, 6.0, 4.0, 4.0, 9.0)
```

Update :

Here is what I have so far :

```
object kmeans {
  println("Welcome to the Scala worksheet")       //> Welcome to the Scala worksheet

case class Point(label : String, points : List[Double])

    val k = 3                                 //> k  : Int = 3

  def distance(l1: (Point, Point)) = {

    val t = l1._1.points.zip(l1._2.points)
    t.map(m => Math.abs(m._1 - m._2)).sum

  }                                               //> distance: (l1: (kmeans.Point, kmeans.Point))Double

  val points = List(("A1,2,10"), ("A2,2,5"), ("A3,8,4"), ("A4,5,8"), ("A5,7,5"), ("A6,6,4"), ("A7,1,2"), ("A8,4,9"))
                                                  //> points  : List[String] = List(A1,2,10, A2,2,5, A3,8,4, A4,5,8, A5,7,5, A6,6,
                                                  //| 4, A7,1,2, A8,4,9)

  var initialCenters : List[Point] = List(Point("A1",List(2, 10)), Point("A4",List(5, 8)), Point("A7",List(1, 2)))
                                                  //> initialCenters  : List[kmeans.Point] = List(Point(A1,List(2.0, 10.0)), Point
                                                  //| (A4,List(5.0, 8.0)), Point(A7,List(1.0, 2.0)))

  val toDouble = points.map(m => new Point(m.split(",").head , m.split(",").tail.map(m2 => m2.toDouble).toList)).toList
                                                  //> toDouble  : List[kmeans.Point] = List(Point(A1,List(2.0, 10.0)), Point(A2,Li
                                                  //| st(2.0, 5.0)), Point(A3,List(8.0, 4.0)), Point(A4,List(5.0, 8.0)), Point(A5,
                                                  //| List(7.0, 5.0)), Point(A6,List(6.0, 4.0)), Point(A7,List(1.0, 2.0)), Point(A
                                                  //| 8,List(4.0, 9.0)))

  val joined = toDouble.map(m => initialCenters.map(p => (m, p))).flatten
                                                  //> joined  : List[(kmeans.Point, kmeans.Point)] = List((Point(A1,List(2.0, 10.0
                                                  //| )),Point(A1,List(2.0, 10.0))), (Point(A1,List(2.0, 10.0)),Point(A4,List(5.0,
                                                  //|  8.0))), (Point(A1,List(2.0, 10.0)),Point(A7,List(1.0, 2.0))), (Point(A2,Lis
                                                  //| t(2.0, 5.0)),Point(A1,List(2.0, 10.0))), (Point(A2,Li
                                                  //| Output exceeds cutoff limit.

   val grouped = joined.map(m => (m, distance(m))).grouped(k).toList
                                                  //> grouped  : List[List[((kmeans.Point, kmeans.Point), Double)]] = List(List(((
                                                  //| Point(A1,List(2.0, 10.0)),Point(A1,List(2.0, 10.0))),0.0), ((Point(A1,List(2
                                                  //| .0, 10.0)),Point(A4,List(5.0, 8.0))),5.0), ((Point(A1,List(2.0, 10.0)),Point
                                                  //| (A7,List(1.0, 2.0))),9.0)), List(((Point(A2,List(2.0,
                                                  //| Output exceeds cutoff limit.
    val sorted = grouped.map(m => m.sortBy(_._2).take(1)).flatten.map(m => m._1)
                                                  //> sorted  : List[(kmeans.Point, kmeans.Point)] = List((Point(A1,List(2.0, 10.0
                                                  //| )),Point(A1,List(2.0, 10.0))), (Point(A2,List(2.0, 5.0)),Point(A7,List(1.0, 
                                                  //| 2.0))), (Point(A3,List(8.0, 4.0)),Point(A4,List(5.0, 8.0))), (Point(A4,List(
                                                  //| 5.0, 8.0)),Point(A4,List(5.0, 8.0))), (Point(A5,List(
                                                  //| Output exceeds cutoff limit.
    val mapped = sorted.groupBy(_._2).map { case (k, v) => (k, v.map(_._1)) }
                                                  //> mapped  : scala.collection.immutable.Map[kmeans.Point,List[kmeans.Point]] = 
                                                  //| Map(Point(A4,List(5.0, 8.0)) -> List(Point(A3,List(8.0, 4.0)), Point(A4,List
                                                  //| (5.0, 8.0)), Point(A5,List(7.0, 5.0)), Point(A6,List(6.0, 4.0)), Point(A8,Li
                                                  //| st(4.0, 9.0))), Point(A7,List(1.0, 2.0)) -> List(Poin
                                                  //| Output exceeds cutoff limit.

        val averaged = mapped.values.map(m => m.map(m2 => m2.points).transpose.map(xs => xs.sum / xs.size))
                                                  //> averaged  : Iterable[List[Double]] = List(List(6.0, 6.0), List(1.5, 3.5), L
                                                  //| ist(2.0, 10.0))



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KMeans.scala :

```
package com.driver

import com.driver.Functions._

object KMeans extends Application {

  case class Point(label: String, points: List[Double])
  val k = 3

  val points = List(("A1,2,10"), ("A2,2,5"), ("A3,8,4"), ("A4,5,8"), ("A5,7,5"), ("A6,6,4"), ("A7,1,2"), ("A8,4,9"))

  val toDouble: List[Point] = points.map(m => new Point(m.split(",").head, m.split(",").tail.map(m2 => m2.toDouble).toList)).toList
  var initialCenters: List[Point] = util.Random.shuffle(toDouble).take(k)

  val maxNumberOfIterations = 10
  for (i <- 1 to maxNumberOfIterations) {

    initialCenters = getNewCenters(initialCenters , toDouble : List[Point])
    println(initialCenters);
  }

  def getNewCenters(initialCenters: List[Point] , toDouble : List[Point]) : List[Point] = {

    val joined = toDouble.map(m => initialCenters.map(p => (m, p))).flatten

    val grouped = joined.map(m => (m, distance(m))).grouped(k).toList

    val sorted = grouped.map(m => m.sortBy(_._2).take(1)).flatten.map(m => m._1)

    val mapped = sorted.groupBy(_._2).map { case (k, v) => (k, v.map(_._1)) }

    val vv = mapped.values.map(p => (p.map(_.points)))

    try {   
      val averaged = mapped.values.map(p => (p.map(_.points).transpose.map(xs => xs.sum / xs.size), p.map(_.label)))
      println("averaged is "+averaged.map(m => m._2))

      averaged.map(m => Point("", m._1)).toList
    }
      catch {
       case e: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException => e.printStackTrace(); println("If reading from file, ensure values no blank lines")
       List[Point]()
    }

  }

}
```

Functions.scala :

```
package com.driver

import com.driver.KMeans.Point;

object Functions {

  def distance(l1: (Point, Point)) = {

    val t = l1._1.points.zip(l1._2.points)
    t.map(m => Math.abs(m._1 - m._2)).sum

  }


}
```